# win32com PyIDispatch property lost on class creation

Tags: python, win32com

I tried this:

```
class A(IntelliCAD.IIcadApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        self = (win32com.client.Dispatch('Icad.Application'))
        print dir(self)           



a = A()
print dir(a)
```

and got the following output:

```
['CLSID', 'DefineFunction', 'GetInterfaceObject', 'Help',
'IsFunctionLoaded', 'ListSDS', 'LoadDVB', 'LoadLISP', 'LoadSDS',
'Quit', 'RunCommand', 'RunMacro', 'RunScript', 'UndefineFunction',
'UnloadDVB', 'UnloadSDS', '_ApplyTypes_', '__doc__', '__eq__',
'__getattr__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__repr__',
'__setattr__', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_',
'_oleobj_', '_prop_map_get_', '_prop_map_put_', 'coclass_clsid']

['CLSID', 'DefineFunction', 'GetInterfaceObject', 'Help',
'IsFunctionLoaded', 'ListSDS', 'LoadDVB', 'LoadLISP', 'LoadSDS',
'Quit', 'RunCommand', 'RunMacro', 'RunScript', 'UndefineFunction',
'UnloadDVB', 'UnloadSDS', '_ApplyTypes_', '__doc__', '__eq__',
'__getattr__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__repr__',
'__setattr__', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_',
'_prop_map_get_', '_prop_map_put_', 'coclass_clsid']
```

The only difference is `_oleobj_` which is somehow lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you, how did you do the formating? I tried but couldn't figure out how. Where can I get help on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple )
When you assign Dispatch to "self" you create new other object which hides local variable. You CANNOT replace object, because you haven't acces to pointers in Python.

Use object you need:

```
a1 = A()
# or
a2 = win32com.client.Dispatch('Icad.Application')
```

Not necessary use classes everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, I still have to grab the concepts of python to full extend.